# Yii gridview CHTML::dropdown as value doesn't work

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'am trying to implement a dropdownlist inside the gridview, but it is not working.

Here's my code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'user-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->roadies_search(),
'filter' =>$model,
'columns'=>array(

    array(
        'name'=>'hname_search',
        'header'=>'Hospital Name',
        'value'=>'($data->AssociatedHospitals) ? $data->AssociatedHospitals : ""',
    ),
    array(
        'type'=>'raw',
        'header'=>'Users',
        'id' => 'test',
        'value'=>function(){
                $res=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT name,id FROM med_user WHERE rank>3")->queryAll();
                $html = '<select name="user" style="width:100%;">
                <option selected>Select User</option>
                ';
                foreach ($res as $key) {
                    $html.='<option value="'.$key['id'].'">'.$key['name'].'</option>
                    ';
                }
                $html.='</select>';
                return $html;
            },
        ),
)

));
```

I have tried it using the following function too:

```
public function getUsername(){
    $res=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT name,id FROM med_user WHERE rank>3")->queryAll();
    return CHtml::dropDownList('usersselectlist'.$this->id,'user_id',CHtml::listData($res, 'id', 'name'));
}
```

I want to show all the users as a dropdown, for every row in the gridview.

**EDIT**

I figured out that the dropdown works fine for firefox, but the problem is with chrome. It is not showing the selected values.

Here's an example

**Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3pr3.png**

**Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAw6g.png**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'user-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->roadies_search(),
'filter' =>$model,
'columns'=>array(

    array(
        'name'=>'hname_search',
        'header'=>'Hospital Name',
        'value'=>'($data->AssociatedHospitals) ? $data->AssociatedHospitals : ""',
    ),
    array(
        'type'=>'raw',
        'header'=>'Users',
        'id' => 'test',
        'value'=>function(){
                // but better prepare data in model and set here from controller
                $dataReader = Yii::app()
                    ->db
                    ->createCommand("SELECT name,id FROM med_user WHERE rank>3")
                    ->query();
                $dropList = array();
                foreach ($dataReader as $row) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $dropList[$id] = $row['name'];
                }
                return CHtml::dropDownList('my', null/* or selected id */, $dropList);
            },
        ),
)

));
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help but the chrome still doesn't show any selected options. Can you confirm that thus works for you?

Comment: for example selected item with id = 1. return CHtml::dropDownList('my', 1, $dropList);

Comment: Please go through the screenshots I provided, the problem is google chrome doesn't show any values in select box when manually selecting the options from dropdown.

Comment: check DOM elements in Chrome & FF. Check styles,js,console. I think problem on front end. Because in my project dropDown working fine in chrome. http://prntscr.com/7ap5n8

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes. But dropdown without styles. Try to check dropdown without any styles and any js(i think selectboxes, select2 etc). Just original html select.

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad way. You will do SQL query for each row, why not use it outside of grid?

```
    $res=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT name,id FROM med_user WHERE rank>3")->queryAll();
    $select_data = CHtml::listData($res, 'id', 'name');

    ......

        array(
                'type'=>'raw',
                'header'=>'Users',
                'id' => 'test',
                'value'=>function($data) use ($select_data){
                        return CHtml::dropDownList('usersselectlist'.$data->id','',$select_data);
                    },
                ),
    .......
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now the only problem I'm facing is that it is not working for chrome. Can you help me with that?